# AWS CodeArtifact with multiple private repositories

Tags: npm, aws-codeartifact, npm-registry

`npm` provides a great way of [associating a scope with a registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry) but I don't really see it working with AWS CodeArtifact.

I expect that once you created a domain `@myco` and a couple of repositories under that domain, ex: `@myco/repo-a` & `@myco/repo-b` I would be able to:

```
npm config set @myco:registry https://888999.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/npm/

npm config set //888999.d.codeartifact.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/npm/:_authToken=xxx
```

and all repositories could be installed with the same `authToken`, but `aws codeartifact login` expects repository which makes me think that it's not possible to install 2 private repos using one token.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I found out the root of the confusion, let me post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The root of my confusion was an assumption that AWS CodeArtifact has the following hierarchy:

- Domains - I've interpreted that as a namespace

  - Repositories - I've interpreted that as list of npm packages

In fact, it's slightly different:

- Domains - is a namespace/domain

  - Repositories - list of different repositories/registries

    - Where we can push lots of npm packages

As result generated token works as expected if we configure global `.npmrc` like this:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/
@myco:registry=https://xxx.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/npm/registry/
//xxx.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/npm/registry/:always-auth=true
//xxx.d.codeartifact.region.amazonaws.com/npm/registry/:_authToken=${CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

That works for both default npm registry and your own.